# Almost the same UUID for two different drives

Tags: windows, mount, uuid

While running the mountvol command on Windows, I see that two of my drives have almost the same UUID, differing only in one byte in the 8th hex character. One of those is not mounted to anything; the other is the C: drive.  Why might this be the case?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLdHR.jpg?

Answer (score 1):

Likely those are the [time based UUID variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687505/uuid-format-8-4-4-4-12-why). It is overwhelmingly likely there would be more differences for the random or hashed variants. (Could tell which with more of the bits. You obscured the full value which isn't really necessary.)

These are constructed with a timestamp, an incrementing clock sequence, and a node identifier. So you can assume that they were generated very soon after each other, on the same system.

Even if this was a collision (it isn't) UUID doesn't guarantee uniqueness.